# Reference NHibernate application for ASP.NET

Tags: nhibernate, reference

I've seen the question for MVC ASP.NET, but was wondering if there was a solid implementation for ASP.NET? Anyone know of a web app with a solid implementation of NHibernate that doesn't have odd crashes to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of a vague question, and I can't provide you with an application you can look at yourself, but I can assure you that the company I work at have built several applications using NHibernate with or without ASP.NET MVC (if not using MVC, we're using WebForms). I can't really see why using MVC or not would make NHibernate less reliable than in any other setting. And NHibernate is usually *very* reliable, in my opinion.

Having said that, there's plenty of gotchas when setting up the infrastructure for NHibernate the first time, so that might be the problem in your case.

Please ask some more specific questions about the issues you have, for example including stack traces of the crashes you're seeing.

Comment: Also use one NH session/transaction per request in your ASP.NET (MVC) application this will lead to better  performance...

Comment: @Darius Kucinskas: totally agree, that's one of the things I mean might be a bit hard to get right the first time, but it's essential to get good performance and a reliable application (otherwise, you might get more than one thread using the same session, which isn't allowed, for example).